# Strategy to conduct regression modelling within R

Tags: r, data.table, linear-regression, data-analysis

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but let me try anyway. 
I would like to conduct a structured analysis of a data set using linear regressions. I thought it would be a good idea to start off with creating a data frame / table where each row comprises one of the models that I would like to analyze. I would then continue to define the dependent variable (y) and the independent variables (x). Define the formulas and so one. Based on that table I would like to run a regression for each model and use these models to calculate new columns like R2 or AIC in my model table to compare models. I would also like to do this because I might have to compare different subsets of the original data for which I would account for with an additional column. 
As a MWE, I was thinking of something like this.

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)
#data
dt<-data.table(mtcars)
#define possible models
models<-data.table(Number=1:2, y="mpg", x=c("cyl", "cyl + gear"))
models[,formula:=paste0(y," ~ ", x)]
#List for model objects
model.objects<-list()
model.objects[models$Number]<-list(NULL)

#my regression function
myreg.function<-function(model){
   summary(lm(models[Number==model,formula],data=dt))
}
#run regression models for each model number
model.objects<-lapply(models$Number,myreg.function)
#Extract R2 from each model and write it into the data tabele
models$R2<-lapply(model.objects, function(x) x[["r.squared"]])
```

Is this a sensible way to do this? Should I rather use more lists? I think it would be rather tedious to create objects with specific descriptions for each model. Any suggestions what I should read to learn about a better way to this in a well-structured manner?

This is purely a application / implementation question, not about how I should o this abstractly. R squared is just an example. I am realtively aware of the econometrics of model choices etc. nd that the number of models can increas exponentially. At least I hope so. I rather want to specify 3-5 types of models and compare them in a structured way withine one table or list by exanding those 3-5 models by variants using log values, or different subsets of the data, so that the table would expand times 2-5 times.

Comment: Why not if this makes sense for you... Note that comparing the R² for models with different numbers of explanatory variables is not very useful (R² will always increase if you add more explanatory variables). Using `x[["adj.r.squared"]]` or the AIC is more meaningful. Note however that you cannot compare the AIC (and maybe not the adjusted R² either ?) between models based on different subsets of the data.

Comment: Note also that some packages can compute models with all possible combinations of explanatory variables for a given dataset (eg function `dredge` in the package `MuMin`) and provide AIC, AICc and other related metrics. The number of possible models increases quickly with the number of explanatory variables and if you have a clear idea of a restricted number of models to evaluate it is better to specify each model as you do.

Comment: Thanks I have a look at the `dredge` function. I also specified my questions, that it is more about the implementation of analyzing a subset of models with different variations, that I think are interesting to look at